# addition of diagonals on a 2d array

Tags: java

I have this code that was written by my professor but i dont fully understand how the diagonal loops are working, it was my work to complete the rows and columns for loops, so i understand what is going on there. The array works like a table, like this:

```
 int [][] square = {
//colums 0   1  2   3
     //0{16, 3, 2, 13},
     //1{5, 10, 11, 8},
     //2{9, 6, 7, 12 },
     //3{4, 15, 14, 1}};
```

The parts i dont understand are the for loops  that are counting through the diagonals, if i wanted to take the value of the first element i would select position [0][0], lets say i wanted to select the value 10
i would go for [1][1] etc. i just dont see how this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
           {
              sum += square[i][i];
           }
```

selects all of the diagonal values, im sorry but it makes no sense to me. Could someone shed some light.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] square = {
        {16, 3, 2, 13},
        {5, 10, 11, 8},
        {9, 6, 7, 12 },
        {4, 15, 14, 1}


      }; 
   System.out.println("Is magic square: " + magicSquare(square));   
 }
   private static boolean magicSquare(int[][] square){

   //calculate the sum of the first row and assign it to n
       int n = sumOfRow(square[0]);

       for (int[] row : square)
       {
          int sum = sumOfRow(row);        
          if (sum != n)
          return false;   
       }
       int sum = 0;

       //rows
      for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++){
          sum = 0;
          for (int j = 0; j < square.length; j++){
              sum += square[i][j];
          }
          if(sum != n){
             return false;
          }
      }
       // columns

       for(int i =0; i < square.length; i++){
           sum = 0;

           for(int j = 0; j< square.length; j++){
               sum += square[j][i];
           }
           if(sum != n){
               return false;
           }
       }
       //diagonal from top left corner to bottom right corner
       sum = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
       {
          sum += square[i][i];
       }
       if (sum != n)
          return false;

       sum = 0;
       // top right to bottom left diagonal
       for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
       {
          sum += square[i][square.length - 1 - i];
       }
       if (sum != n)
          return false;
       return true;

    } 

   //returns the sum of the elements in the row
   private static int sumOfRow(int[] row){
      int sum = 0;
      for(int el : row){
         sum += el;
      }
      return sum;
   }
```

Comment: `square[i][i]` is either `square[0][0]`, `square[1][1]`, `square[2][2]`, or `square[3][3]`. It doesn't select *all* diagonal values, though, since there is two diagonals, not just one (top right to bottom left, and top left to bottom right which is the one we've gone for here in our example).

Comment: For the other diagonal you'd do `square[i][square.length-1-i]` just as it says in your code. So the different values are `square[0][3]`, `square[1][2]`, `square[2][1]`, and `square[3][0]`.

Comment: i should have done a better job at explaining what im trying to understand. I understand there is two different diagonals , hence two different for loops. i dont get whats going on in either one.

Comment: You said yourself that you would use `square[0][0]` for the first value, and `square[1][1]` for the `10`. Surely you can see that if you continue with `square[2][2]` and `square[3][3]` you'll get the whole diagonal. Is the problem that you don't actually understand how a [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) works?

Comment: i know what a for loop does, the square size is [4][4], correct?

Comment: The size is `4`, yes, which means that there are four different indices, and they are `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`. The last index is always one less than the length of the array, because the first index is 0.

Comment: so the for loop says, if i is less than 4 take sum which is 0 , and add 1, so at the end of the loop, i turns into a 3 and that 3 is placed into [i][i]

Comment: `sum += square[i][i]` is the same as `sum = sum + square[i][i]` here. `sum` starts at `0`. On the first iteration of the loop, `16` gets added to `sum`. On the second iteration, `10` gets added to `sum`, etc.

Comment: seems like i need to break out some paper, and put it to manual test. Thanks for the explanation and the documentation links.

Comment: Note that nothing is *placed into* `square[i][i]`. Values are *taken* from `square[i][i]` and added to `sum`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this will help. For a 4 x 4 array you can 'unwind' the code replacing `i` with the values in the for loop:

```
   //diagonal from top left corner to bottom right corner
   sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
   {
      sum += square[i][i];
   }
   if (sum != n)
      return false;

   sum = 0;
   // top right to bottom left diagonal
   for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
   {
      sum += square[i][square.length - 1 - i];
   }
   if (sum != n)
      return false;
```

Would become:

```
   sum = 0;
   sum += square[0][0];
   sum += square[1][1];
   sum += square[2][2];
   sum += square[3][3];
   if (sum != n)
      return false;

   sum = 0;
   sum += square[0][3];
   sum += square[1][2];
   sum += square[2][1];
   sum += square[3][0];
   if (sum != n)
      return false;
```

I hope that makes it clear: it's summing up each of the diagonals in turn and comparing to the target value.

Comment: allright i see what is doing, the i from the for loop is changing value as the for loop increases and those values are being passed into the positions [] [] in turn this is what decides what positions are being selected and checked.

Comment: @mrKapplan Precisely.

Comment: wow!! this is complicated to understand. You guys are more helpful than my professor.

Comment: ok i get it, can i shut down the question now, before the down votes pile up?

Comment: @mrKapplan The downvotes are probably mainly because you are not clear on what exactly you don't understand, so we have to guess. You can either delete the question and move on, or improve it if you feel it needs improvement in hopes of reversing the downvotes. Deleting is probably appropriate, as these kinds of questions arise as a cause of lack of very basic Java knowledge - and Stack Overflow is not a place for a Java tutorial.

Comment: I'll take it and learn from my experience, i also feel it would be disrespectful to sprinter, he typed a neat explanation.